# Elegant construct to test&branch according to the previous command result

Tags: bash

I am looking for an elegant way of testing the result of the last executed command and branch depending on the result. The construct I want to build upon is the following:

```
if /bin/true ; then
  do_stuff
fi
```

This works great when we want to test for success. But how can I test for failure? When I'm doing intensive error checking, what I want to do is the equivalent of this:

```
if ! /bin/true ; then
  do_error_handling
fi
```

The best solution I have found so far is to define two simple macros in my scripts:

```
onSuccess() { [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; }
onError () { [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; }
```

Then I can do stuff like this:

```
some_command
if onError ; then
  # error handling block
fi
```

But I would prefer a lot more using something built in in bash so I don't have to replicate these macros in every script I write.

This "problem" of mine is a lot about the style of code I want to write. I want to escape the repetitive `if [ $? -ne 0 ]` ugliness.

Comment: Remember this is much about style. Forget about using complete if..else block if I don't need them.

Comment: There is "true" and "false" that are built-in bash commands. Using /bin/true specifically executes a sub-process where it is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. I already knew the || operator but I hadn't yet thought of combining it with braces.

```
/bin/false || {
  echo err handling 
  echo more handling
}
```

or

```
/bin/true && {
  echo stuff on success 
  echo more stuff
}
```

This construct does not aim to replace an if..else. It is only useful when you're interested with either success OR failure.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build upon:

```
if /bin/true ; then
    do_stuff
fi
```

Try:

```
if /bin/true ; then    # success
    do_nothing
else                   # failure / error
    do_stuff
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can use this:

```
first_command && command_if_true || command_if_false
```

Refer to [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3) for the associated pitfalls. Basically: `command_if_true` returning `false` breaks it.

Here is a workaround (I think):

```
( first_command && command_if_true || /bin/true ) || command_if_false
```

But whether it is worth it, or better looking than the straightforward tests, is subjective.

Comment: sure. No need of the true condition here. User wants only the `||` part.

Answer (score 1):

Basically,

```
if something
then :
   # nothing (colon on previous line is a no-op command)
else
   abcdef
endif
```

is equivalent to

```
( something || abcdef )
```

Comment: This construct does not allow a block with multiple instructions.